# Python/Tkinter: Stretch an image horizontally?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter

Is it possible to stretch an image horizontally?

Use case: I have a one pixel wide (60 pixel tall) image that I would like to stretch horizontally to fill its parent container. The purpose of stretching this image is to give the container in question the appearance of a gradient background.

Here's what I tried without success (the gradient image shows up, but just centers itself vs. stretching):

```
import Tkinter as tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()

image = tkinter.PhotoImage( file='gradient1.gif' )
imgBackground = tkinter.Label( image=image )
imgBackground.pack( side='top', fill='x', expand=True )

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to stretch an image to fill the container. However, you can detect when a widget changes size and you can "repaint" the gradient. Use a canvas, and create a binding to `<Configure>` that draws the gradient. It sounds slow but it's plenty fast enough assuming you don't have hundreds of these.

Comment: Bryan: When you say draw my gradient, are you suggesting that I use something like create_line() to draw each line of the gradient vs. using an image? Clever! If I do this, can I take my collection of colored lines (as a tagged group?) and move them to another canvas or can I move my canvas (with colored lines) to another container so that I can re-use my gradient background effect? My confusion lies with how canvases and frames work together, eg. can I place a (transparent) frame on top of a canvas and/or can I place a canvas behind an existing frame? (Or must I use create_window for these?)

Comment: @Malcolm: yes, draw each line of the gradient. You can use a canvas in place of a frame (versus placing a transparent frame over the canvas, which isn't possible).

Comment: Thanks for your patience - I've never used the Tkinter Canvas before although I've read the effbot documentation on this widget many times today :) When you say I can use a canvas in place of a frame, does this mean I can grid/pack/place my child widgets into a canvas vs. frame using the exact same grid/pack/place syntax and behavior? Would it be fair to say that a Canvas is like an enhanced Frame whose background I can draw shapes and images on? If this is all true, then why would I use create_window() vs. the conventional grid/pack/layout to place my child widgets? Thank you Bryan!